# Scala Traits - How to extend a trait multiple times?

Tags: scala, decorator, traits

I am noob to Scala, please see the following code.

```
abstract class Pizza() {
  def toppings: List[String]
  def price: BigDecimal
}
trait Large extends Pizza {
  abstract override def price: BigDecimal = super.price * 2
}
trait Cheese extends Pizza {
  abstract override def toppings: List[String] = "Cheese" :: super.toppings
  abstract override def price: BigDecimal = super.price + 0.5
}
trait Salami extends Pizza {
  abstract override def toppings: List[String] = "Salami" :: super.toppings
  abstract override def price: BigDecimal = super.price + 1.0
}
class BasePizza extends Pizza {
  def toppings = List("Tomato Sauce")
  def price = 5.0
}
class MargheritaPizza extends BasePizza with Cheese
class LargeMargheritaPizza extends MargheritaPizza with Large
class SalamiPizza extends MargheritaPizza with Salami
class DoubleCheeseSalamiPizza extends MargheritaPizza with Salami with Cheese


println(reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[DoubleCheeseSalamiPizza].baseClasses)
// List(class DoubleCheeseSalamiPizza, trait Salami, class MargheritaPizza, trait Cheese, class BasePizza, class Pizza, class Object, class Any) res0: Unit = ()
```

How can I add a decoration multiple times? for example a Pizza with double cheese ? (As you can see in the linearization order `trait Cheese` is extended one time)

Comment: Rather `sealed trait Pizza{ ...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Base classes can occur in linearization only once:

https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/05-classes-and-objects.html#class-linearization

> Let `C` be a class with template `C1 with ... with Cn { stats }`. The linearization of `C`, `L(C)` is defined as follows:
>
> `L(C) = C, L(Cn) +⃗ … +⃗ L(C1)`
>
> Here `+⃗` denotes concatenation where elements of the right operand replace
>   identical elements of the left operand:
>
> ```
> a, A +⃗ B = a, (A +⃗ B)  if a ∉ B
>          = A +⃗ B       if a ∈ B
> ```

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/reflect/scala/reflect/api/Types.scala#L176-L180

> ```
> /** The list of all base classes of this type (including its own typeSymbol)
>  *  in linearization order, starting with the class itself and ending
>  *  in class Any.
>  */ def baseClasses: List[Symbol]
> ```

Comment: How to implement such a solution in Scala?